# Using Parallel.Foreach after execution application hangs

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

```
PopulateTable(DataTable filterTable, TableDef contextTableDef)
{
    string friendlyFieldName = "";
    string friendlyTableName = "";
    string friendlyFullName = "";
    try
    {            
     *For loop commented*
    //foreach (FieldDef field in contextTableDef.Fields) {
    //friendlyTableName = contextTableDef.Description;
    //friendlyFieldName = field.FriendlyName;
    //friendlyFullName = friendlyTableName + "." + friendlyFieldName;
    //if (!field.CurrentView.TimeField) {
        //filterTable.Rows.Add(contextTableDef.Name, friendlyFullName, //contextTableDef.Name, field.Name, friendlyFieldName, friendlyTableName);
    //}

        Parallel.ForEach(contextTableDef.Fields, (field) =>
        {
            friendlyTableName = contextTableDef.Description;
            friendlyFieldName = field.FriendlyName;
            friendlyFullName = friendlyTableName + "." + friendlyFieldName;
            if (!field.CurrentView.TimeField) {
                filterTable.Rows.Add(contextTableDef.Name, friendlyFullName, contextTableDef.Name, field.Name, friendlyFieldName, friendlyTableName);
            }

        });

        foreach (TableDef childTable in contextTableDef.Children) {
            if (childTable.IsOneToOne) {
                PopulateFilterTable(filterTable, childTable);
            }
        }

        return filterTable;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Used here Parallel.Foreach instead of for loop to increase performance.Here in code i used custom collection TableDef,FiledDef.
When i run the code and observed that the loop completed but the application is hanged not able recognized why is it so.

Comment: You probably shouldn't manipulate the table inside the parallel code, the DataTable is not thread-safe when writing to it.

Comment: Same as what Lasse wrote, with an additional link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21310757/thread-safety-for-datatable

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: If DataTable is not thread safe as per your suggestion what should i use to increase the performance of traditional for each loop which contains millions of records.Here also you seethe function is calling recursively

Comment: Use `BlockingCollection` and producer/consumer pattern

Comment: Well... don't put the millions of records in a DataTable? Why do you put them in a DataTable?

Comment: What makes you think the loop runs infinitely? It's more likely to **run for a long time**. What kind of analysis did you make? Try to increment a counter (with `Interlocked.Increment`) and output it every 1000 times to see the execution time of your loop.

Comment: Actually the application is hang when used Parallel.ForEach

Comment: That's not enough. **Where** does the application hang? At what line exactly?

Comment: @VMAtm: How should implement BlockingCollection and producer/consumer pattern in my function

Comment: one thread is doing the recursive add, one thread is consuming the blocking collection. After recursive is over, complete the collection.

Comment: @VMAtm: Can u please code for this,didn' have any idea about your suggested approach.

Comment: You really should google samples for this. This is quite easy and you can do that by yourself.

Comment: @NKD note that this will not solve your issue. You should of course use thread safe collection (such as  `BlockingCollection` as VMAtm suggested), **but that will not solve your issue**.