# Visual Studio 2022 debug step through keeps going back to top of code

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have the following lines of code:

[image]

But when I press F11 to step through the code, it hits the highlighted line, then jumps back to line 185, then I might be able to step through to line 198, and then it will jump back to the top to line 185.

I have had a look at a number of articles on debugging in VS2022, but I cannot find anything related to this issue. I have not encountered it before and was wondering if anyone else had any ideas on what could be causing the issue?

There are no errors, the code seems to run fine, but it will sometimes sit on the one line for about 10 key presses before it moves onto the next line.

Under diagnostics/events it shows the code going from line 185/186 and back numerous times.

[image]

I have checked out

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp

I deleted the suo and obj and bin folders as per ['Step Into' is suddenly not working in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801385/step-into-is-suddenly-not-working-in-visual-studio)

But it got to line 204 and then jumped back to 185. No errors or exceptions that I can see.

Any one have any ideas on what else I can look at or try?

Regards,
Darren

Comment: Is your program perhaps processing multiple requests?

Comment: Does it seem similar to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76361336/vs-2022-debugger-steps-twice-on-the-same-line-of-c-sharp-code-windows-service  If you see the yellow-ish background of the current line change to a more dull yellow after stepping over, then you are switching threads (basically what Apodemus's comment is about). You can also confirm if you switched threads by looking at the top toolbar and noting the thread number before and after stepping over. If this is the case, its normal behavior (or maybe not depending on what you want your application to be doing!)

Comment: Yep, it looks like the event from one of the controls via JavaScript was continually calling a function that was calling the Get Action which was restarting the whole process over again on a different thread. Changed where the Get action was called from and everything is working ok now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.